# Docker - Full functional WordPress (WP+DB+PHPMyAdmin)

Tags: php, wordpress, docker

I try to have a full wordpress service working on a container with mariaDB and PHPMyAdmin. I can only find outdated (like v1 docker-compose) help online.

I try with this docker-compose.yml file :

Edited files:

```
version: '2'
services:
  wordpress:
    image: wordpress:latest
    networks:
      - front
      - back
    ports:
      - 8080:80
    environment:
      WORDPRESS_DB_PASSWORD: examplepass
      WORDPRESS_DB_NAME: wpdb
      WORDPRESS_TABLE_PREFIX: wp_
      WORDPRESS_DB_HOST: wordpress_db
    volumes:
      - ./wordpress-data:/var/www/html
      - ./php/uploads.ini:/usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/uploads.ini
  wordpress_db:
    image: mariadb:latest
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: examplepass
    volumes:
      - wordpress-db-data:/var/lib/mysql
    networks:
      - back
  phpmyadmin:
    image: phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin
    networks:
      - back
    ports:
      - 8181:80
volumes:
    wordpress-db-data:
      driver: local
networks:
  front:
  back:
```

I can hit PHPMA on 8181 but I cannot hit WP on 8080.

Any idea ?

EDIT: I made some change. WP is running now but I cannot connect my user root/examplepass to PMAdmin.
I have an error like this 
`#2002 - php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: Name does not resolve &mdash; The server is not responding (or the local server's socket is not correctly configured).`

Comment: post `docker port $(docker ps -q)`

Comment: wouldn't your WORDPRESS_DB_HOST be wp_db instead of db?

Comment: `docker port $(docker ps -q)` ->

`"docker port" requires at least 1 and at most 2 argument(s).
See 'docker port --help'.

Usage:  docker port CONTAINER [PRIVATE_PORT[/PROTO]]

List port mappings or a specific mapping for the container`

Comment: @user3012759 I change it. I cannot reach my WP still

Comment: @Ragnar, can verify that WP is actually running and maybe test if you can reach it from other containers?

Comment: @user3012759 You are right. WP is lunching but suddenly I cannot see my container.

Comment: I made some modification now WP is working. PMAdmin won't let me connect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally got it.

I need the var env `PMA_HOST: wordpress_db` on PMA.

So my final .yml file :

```
version: '2'
services:
  wordpress:
    image: wordpress:latest
    networks:
      - front
      - back
    ports:
      - 8080:80
    environment:
      WORDPRESS_DB_PASSWORD: examplepass
      WORDPRESS_DB_NAME: wpdb
      WORDPRESS_TABLE_PREFIX: wp_
      WORDPRESS_DB_HOST: wordpress_db
    volumes:
      - ./wordpress-data:/var/www/html
      - ./php/uploads.ini:/usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/uploads.ini
  wordpress_db:
    image: mariadb:latest
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: examplepass
    volumes:
      - wordpress-db-data:/var/lib/mysql
    networks:
      - back
  phpmyadmin:
    image: phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin:latest
    networks:
      - back
    ports:
      - 8181:80
    environment:
      MYSQL_USERNAME: root
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: examplepass
      PMA_HOST: wordpress_db
volumes:
    wordpress-db-data:
      driver: local
networks:
  front:
  back:
```

Answer (score 1):

Honestly I think you're approaching this wrong. The best way is to set all the environment variables on the DB container so that it (a) provisions the accounts and DB, and then link it to the web container.

Once the web container starts, it will have access to the MYSQL_... variables since they were derived on the DB container. Start with The DB container, link to wordpress, then link DB to PHPMyadmin as well.

Comment: I read that links are deprecated in the favor of network with docker-compose v2.

Comment: Only for services not individual containers